# Proof for inequality involving mean of $k$ closest values

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, computer-science

Let $X = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ where $x_i \in \mathrm{R}$.
Given a fixed positive integer $k$, let $N^{X}_k(x_i) \subset X$ denote the set of $k$ values from $X$ that are closest to $x_i$ (in absolute value). Example, if $X = \{6, 4, 2, 7, 19, 9, 22\}$ and $k=3$, then $N^{X}_k(7) = \{6, 7, 9\}$.

For each $x_i \in X$, let us define $y_i$ as the mean of $N^{X}_k(x_i)$. This gives $Y = \{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$.

How can one prove the following (I tried experimentally on some examples and it seems to hold) :
$$\sum_{y_i \in Y} \sum_{y_j \in N^{Y}_k(y_i)} |y_i - y_j| \leq \sum_{x_i \in X} \sum_{x_j \in N^{X}_k(x_i)} |x_i - x_j|$$

One simple intuition is that our averaging is smoothing the data, but I couldn't find from where to start to prove the above inequality.

Comment: how are you defining that "closeness?" Would 10 have been in it? 15? Why stop at 9? That is ambiguous here.

Comment: @dezdichado $N^X_k(x_i) \subset X$. 10 and 15 are not in $X$ in my example. To find $N^X_k(x_i)$ just rank the values of $X$ in assenting order according to their distance to $x_i$, and take the top $k$ ones. I hope this is clearer ?

Comment: @dezdichado any ideas ?